# PHP: Loading a specific area dependent on selected option

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a drop down menu with dynamically set values from the database:

When a value is selected how could I make it load a specific `view` dependent on what the selected option is?

I now have it loading a specific view dependent on what option is selected:

**Code:**

```
        if (isset($_REQUEST['general_options'])) {

            $page = strtolower(str_replace(" ", "", $_REQUEST['general_options']));


            $this->load->view( $page, $data, FALSE);
        }
```

**How could I dynamically produce a form with specific questions dependent on what question is selected?**

**HTML:**

```
<label for="general_options">Quote Type: </label>
    <select name="general_options" id="general_options">

        <option value="Graphic Design">Graphic Design</option>


        <option value="Content Management System">Content Management System</option>


        <option value="Shopping Cart">Shopping Cart</option>


        <option value="E-Mail Marketing">E-Mail Marketing</option>

            </select>
```

Comment: Do you mind posting some code? It helps us to give you the best answer possible...

Comment: @ews2001 I will try but I do not have much currently only html

Comment: And where is the jquery and php code? What have you tried except writing the html?

Comment: @itachi I will remove that line its confusing people

Comment: @Jess: it is not confusing people. You can approach this in two way. Preload the content, hide it with javascript and then show on the event or use ajax. Your question at this point says,"give me the whole code." and as you already know, these type questions won't get any answers. You should try 1st, then post the code which isn't working. Then i'l modify it so that it works.

Comment: @itachi Thanks, I have just modified the question as I have some of the code working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think php will be overkill for this. I have used jquery for this. you can find the [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/gePcu/1/)

```
<label for="general_options">Quote Type: </label>
    <select name="general_options" id="general_options">
        <option value="graphic">Graphic Design</option>
        <option value="content">Content Management System</option>
        <option value="shopping">Shopping Cart</option>
        <option value="marketing">E-Mail Marketing</option>
</select><br/>

<div id="graphic" style="display:none;" class="questions">
    <p>Graphic content 1</p>
    <p>Graphic content 2</p>
    <p>Graphic content 3</p>
</div>

<div id="content" style="display:none;" class="questions">
<p>CMS content 1</p>
<p>CMS content 2</p>
<p>CMS content 3</p>
</div>

<div id="shopping" style="display:none;" class="questions">
<p>shopping content 1</p>
<p>shopping content 2</p>
<p>shopping content 3</p>
</div>

<div id="marketing" style="display:none;" class="questions">
<p>marketing content 1</p>
<p>marketing content 2</p>
<p>marketing content 3</p>
</div>
```

and the jquery Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#general_options').change(function() {

      theVal = $("#general_options").val();
     $('div.questions').each(function(){

        if(this.id == theVal){
            $('div.questions').hide();
            $('#'+this.id).show();
        }
    });         

  });   

});​
    ​
```

Answer (score 0):

For the values of option tags, instead of the text, you could use the `id`s. Then, you could write code(server side) to query the database with the selected id, when the user had submitted the form. If you need it an interactive manner, you could use the AJAX.

In jQuery, there is [get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), [post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) and [ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) methods. You could use one of them.